# QT 5.7 MSVC 2015 Static Builds Not Working

Tags: c++, windows, qt, static-linking

I'm having trouble using my QT 5.7 MSVC 2015 static builds, both 32-bit and 64-bit, on Windows. These are the commands I run and the output I get (tested with 32 bit as well):

```
C:\Users\Josh>set PATH=C:\Qt\static\Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_Static_x64\bin;%PATH%

C:\Users\Josh>cd "\Users\Josh\Mozy Sync\ReplicatorNew\ReplicatorNew"

C:\Users\Josh\Mozy Sync\ReplicatorNew\ReplicatorNew>qmake ReplicatorNew.pro
Could not find qmake configuration file win32-msvc2015.
Error processing project file: ReplicatorNew.pro
```

Here are the steps I followed to configure the QT static builds:

1. Downloaded QT 5.7 source and unzipped to its own directory.
2. Installed QT with QT Creator and msvc2015 32 and 64 bit.
3. Installed Visual Studio 2015 Community with all Visual C++ options
   checked.
4. Installed Strawberry Perl 32 bit and added to path.
5. Installed Python 2.7.12 and added to path.
6. Installed Ruby and added to path.
7. Installed Windows 10 SDK and checked all options in install.
8. Installed jom to its own directory.
9. Downloaded openssl source and built as per [here](https://github.com/alberthdev/alberthdev-misc/wiki/Building-Qt-v5.6-Statically-on-Windows).
10. Edited qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf to the following:

    ```
     QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
     QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += -O2 -MT -Zi
     QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG      = -Zi -MTd
    ```
11. Ran this for 32 bit:

    ```
     cd "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc"
     vcvarsall.bat x86
    ```
12. This for 64 bit:

    ```
     cd "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc"
     vcvarsall.bat amd64
    ```
13. Then these:

    ```
     set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2015
     set QTDIR=C:\Qt\Static\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.7.0\qtbase
     set PATH=C:\Qt\Static\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.7.0\qtbase\bin;%PATH%
     cd C:\Qt\Static\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.7.0
    ```
14. For 32 bit:

    ```
     configure -debug-and-release -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc2015 -opengl desktop -static -target xp -nomake examples -no-compile-examples -nomake tests -prefix C:\Qt\static\MSVC2015_Static_x86 -openssl -L C:\OpenSSL-win32\lib -l libeay32 -l ssleay32 -I C:\OpenSSL-win32\include -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib
    ```
15. For 64 bit:

    ```
     configure -debug-and-release -confirm-license -platform win32-msvc2015 -opengl desktop -static -nomake examples -no-compile-examples -nomake tests -prefix C:\Qt\static\MSVC2015_Static_x64 -openssl -L C:\OpenSSL-win64\lib -l libeay32 -l ssleay32 -I C:\OpenSSL-win64\include -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib
    ```
16. Then ran these:

    ```
     C:\Qt\static\jom_1_1_1\jom.exe -j 4
     C:\Qt\static\jom_1_1_1\jom.exe -j 4 install
    ```

Also definitely verified win32-msvc2015 was in the mkspecs directory of the static build directory. I renamed the qt static dirs to the names in the first code snippet.  I couldn't find much on Google so I post here in hope of help. Thanks. I'm hoping it's simple like I left out a directory to put in the path environment variable...

Comment: Steps #2, #7 and #10 are unnecessary. You do need to set up MSVC for XP [Targeting from the Command Line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012/) for the 32 bit build. Step #13 lines 1-3 are unnecessary.

Comment: Also make sure that you **don't move a Qt install**: it won't work. After `jom install` for Qt, the prefix must remain where it is. Ensure that `qmake -query` returns correct paths. Also ensure that your `.pro` file is sane: perhaps build a simple Qt example first.

Comment: I have a couple questions regarding the steps you said were unnecessary: For step 7 if we compile with -opengl desktop or -opengl dynamic do we need the directx sdk as included with the windows 10 sdk?  Re step 10 do we need to configure with the argument -static-runtime in order to edit the mkspecs file or does configure take care of this automatically for us?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't recall needing to install it with MSVC2015. Maybe I did and I forgot; in that case I apologize. As for step #10 if you want static runtime then yes, pass that to configure, don't edit mkspecs. The whole point of `-static-runtime` is to change those settings. The only reason to mess with Qt sources should be if you intend to modify the code itself, or get the XP target to build. Qt 5.7 won't build for an XP target without one or two one-liner patches. If it does for you then you're not building for XP. **Stock Qt 5.7.0 is not supposed to build for XP without patching!**

Comment: If you follow the [Targeting from the Command Line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012/) instructions, then from the same command shell configure and build Qt with XP target, it should fail. You should be able to figure the patches, or if not ask another question about that. If you haven't run the "Targeting from the Command Line" in a given cmd prompt, then you **can't build for XP**: it won't be for XP. This applies to Qt itself and to **all your projects**. You must launch Qt Creator for XP targeting only from such shell!

Comment: Corollary: while Qt Creator can find where MSVC is, it knows nothing about the XP target SDK subset. Unless the environment is set correctly (e.g. by launching from a preconfigured shell), it won't target XP *even if* Qt itself was compiled to target XP properly.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was I renamed the QT static build directory after the build, which broke it.  Quick fix: rename it to its original **configure -prefix** name.  Thanks Kuba!